# border on rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I have a tab in my header nav that has a border on it. The tab has rounded corners. I want the border on my tab to run flush with the border on my header. But the rounded corners appear to create a taper effect. How can I alleviate this? My fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9rj8/)

css:

```
.gizmo {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#4c4c4c;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
.tab-shit {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    right:100px;
    height:50px;
    top:7px;
    background-color:#4c4c4c;
    border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="gizmo">
    <div class="tab-shit"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you will using `ul` and `li` for making a tab. so using `border-top-left-radius:2em;` and `border-top-right-radius:2em;` you can give round corner on top-left and top-right.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I don't understand what you are trying to say. My fiddle has my `html` markup in it.

Comment: `border on my header` have you applied any border on the header?

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes, please look at my fiddle.

Comment: @jefffabiny what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/S9rj8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.tab-shit {
    height:20px;
    border:5px solid red;
    border-top: none;
    bottom:-25px;                /* -25 = - (height+border) */
    border-radius:0 0 25px 25px; /*  25 =    height+border  */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9rj8/5/)

It works well if you add a `border-bottom` to the header: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9rj8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that the `border-bottom` declaration doesn't affect the left and right, so the browser is trying to make the transition smooth, since by the top ends of the corners it should be using `border-left` and `border-right`.  To fix this, I'd suggest applying the border using a pseudo-element.  So like this:

```
.gizmo {
    /* same */
}
.tab-shiz {
    /* same except no border */
    /* border-bottom:4px solid red; */
}
/* add this */
.tab-shiz:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
}
```

Doing this will let you style the border as you wish without affecting much else in the element.  Careful if you're using CSS transitions, though, as they don't work on generated content.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz47W/)**

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided so far prove that the issue can be solved by adding borders on the left and right and either contracting the DOM element down or clipping it to prevent the left and right borders from appearing above the border of the header div. The tab in my project actually contains an icon, but I simplified it here just to create a proof of my problem. Since my tab contains an icon, I cannot contract the height or clip my element. What I resulted to was using the answers above on a new element that is positioned below my tab. So, my tab is now squared off, and a new `span` under it has rounded corners, border radius, and borders on the left, bottom, and right.